# Lua REGEX, catch parenthesis

Tags: regex, lua, lua-patterns

How catch the values (r = 32, g = 36, b = 51) from this data above?

```
$color1: rgba(32, 36, 51, 1);
```

I try:

```
v = "$color1: rgba(32, 36, 51, 1);"
id, r, g, b = v.match(v, "%$color(%d+)%:%s+rgba%((%d+)%,%s+(%d+)%,%s+(%d+)%,%s+%d+%)%;") or 0, 0, 0, 0
```

But does not work.

Comment: Did any of our answers below help you? Please consider upvoting and accepting the best one.

Answer (score 0):

```
v = "$color1: rgba(32, 36, 51, 1);"
string.gsub(v, "%((%d+),%s(%d+),%s(%d+)", function(r, g, b) print(r, g, b) end)
```

Output: `32 36 51`

Gsub finds occurrences of a pattern in a string and will either replace text with text or in this case, run a function. 
I start my pattern with `%(` because I assume you're only going to run this function on a string that always looks like the one you've given, so there can be no false positives, so it will be pretty safe to just start at the first opening parenthesis. 
Each `%d+` finds one or more digit, and it is wrapped in parentheses so the function can find it later. `,%s` finds a comma and a space between the digits.

`function(r, g, b)` acts where r, g and b are the first, second and third set found in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Your `id, r, g, b = v.match(v, "%$color(%d+)%:%s+rgba%((%d+)%,%s+(%d+)%,%s+(%d+)%,%s+%d+%)%;") or 0, 0, 0, 0` line is parsed by Lua as

```
id = v:match(pattern) or 0
r = 0
g = 0
b = 0
```

Since there is a match, the `id` variable is set to the capturing group 1 value, the rest is assigned with zeros.

You may fix this assignment using tables:

```
result = {string.match(v, "%$color(%d+):%s+rgba%((%d+),%s+(%d+),%s+(%d+),%s+%d+%);")}
id, r, g, b = result[1] or 0, result[2] or 0, result[3] or 0, result[4] or 0
```

See the [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/OCX2MY).

**NOTE**:`;` and `,` are not special Lua pattern characters, hence I removed `%` escapes in front of them in the pattern.